# JSF 2.0 Java EE 6 authentication - Apache Shiro or other libraries?

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jboss6.x

For development of my first JSF 2.0 app I use GlassFish v3.1, deployment is planned on JBoss 6. Are there libraries which work on both servers and support JDBC based login? I have read about [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), is this an option for this scenario or would you recommend a different library?

Answer (score 2):

Shiro should more than meet your needs in a Java EE app. Feel free to ask any questions about it along the way - you'll find a helpful community!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Shiro isn't based on Java EE security. I'd really use the latter (specifying security in web.xml, ejb annotations, ...). A login module in Glassfish (custom or existing one), or the jboss equivalent, should handle authentication/groups/roles. I really wouldn't use a non-standard library where there is a standard solution (=specification-based).

Comment: A Login Module?  No one I've ever met actually likes using JAAS, let alone understands it that well. JEE security is and always will be (like all JEE specs) a 'lowest common denominator' solution.  Also JEE security doesn't handle fine-grained access control for your app - Shiro does.  What matters most is that there is a de-facto solution that caters to what developers actually _want_.  Shiro has been around for 8 years now (previously known as JSecurity), it is an Apache Top Level project with a great community, and will be around for many more years.  It is a very viable choice.

Comment: Well, I'm your counter-example then. :-) I agree it's the 'lowest common denominator', so I'd say use it for what it's designed for and use a specific solution for fine-grained checks (which you can probably make quite simply, querying a specific service you wrote when needed). Let's not go too deep into JEE Specs, but there are a lots of successful examples nowadays.

Comment: It would be interesting if Apache Shiro and JAAS could complement each other since there is an overlap in the authentication features.

Comment: > I really wouldn't use a non-standard library - If you're using GlassFish specific login modules you are doing that too. Why not use or recommend the standard Java EE auth modules? Java EE 6 introduced JASPIC for that.

Comment: @ArjanTijms the glassfish login module isn't standard in itself, but from app perspective, you don't have to use anything but Java EE 6 api's. You could JSR-196 (JASPIC), but it's more focused on the message. You *could* do authentication there, although it's sometimes better to use it for getting the authentication message from http (http basic, form, session, ...) and forwarding to a (proprietary :-( ) login module. Still, the application won't see that and will only use standard API's.